# Android recording voice when a button is clicked

Tags: android, xml, mediarecorder, android-mediarecorder

I have a 'Play'button set up in an XML layout file,

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="play"
    android:onClick="playButton"
 />
```

and I want to make it so that when I click on the button, an action dialog shows in which there are two buttons that say 'Play' and 'Stop'.

When I click on the Play button I want the app to record whatever the user is saying to the microphone and when the 'Stop' button is pressed, save that mp3 into resources.

How can I make this? I'm right now really confused because my 
and yes, I've seen the Android documentation & sample codes on Media Recorder and I still don't get it...

Comment: please try to do something then ask if stuck with it

Answer (score 0):

try to see this resource on Github [android-MediaRecorder](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-MediaRecorder)
make something similar that you dear, but use camera of the devices. By the way you can start from here and make some adjustment

By the way , you can find more project like this, ad example this [AndroidAudioRecorder](https://github.com/adrielcafe/AndroidAudioRecorder)

that are already did.

Maybe this can be help you

Have a nice work!